# Software update preference pane and manual update using terminal both hang

Tags: software-update

Both software update in the Preferences Pane and the manual software update are hanging.

[image]

[image]

What could be the problem?

OSX 10.15.7

Comment: which version of MacOS?

Comment: @slartibartfast 10.15.7

Comment: Restart and reset NVRAM (or PRAM): Hold *Command-Option-P-R* for about 20 seconds. Reset SMC: Hold *Shift-Control-Option* on the left side of the keyboard, and press the power button at the same time. Do you use a VPN? Is this via Wi-Fi or LAN?

Comment: Try it in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`sudo /bin/launchctl kickstart -k system/com.apple.softwareupdated && softwareupdate -l`

..and enter your admin password when prompted.

You might also need to remove the contents of `/Library/Updates/`.

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: `launchctl` is a macOS built-in binary to manage LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons; the first half of the command is telling the OS to restart the LaunchDaemon which initiates a software update check.  By running it under `sudo` the process is elevated and can interact with system-level processes.  The `softwareupdate` (after the `&&`) is simply the command-line interface to Software Update.  (Both commands have extensive `man` entries.)